# C return struct with double

Tags: c

I have some kind of object and three functions. First receives unix timestamp as 8 bytes from interface, second is getter, third is for processing, but there I get `0`:

```
struct structure{
  double timestamp;
}

struct objstruct{
  struct structure struct_in_obj;
}

typedef struct objstruct *Obj; 

Obj newObj() {
    Obj this = (Obj) malloc(sizeof(struct objstruct));
    bzero(this, sizeof(struct objstruct));
    return this;
}   

void setVal(Obj this, char bytes[8]){
      memcpy(&this->struct_in_obj.timestamp, bytes, sizeof(double)); 
      printf("Value set: %d\n", this->struct_in_obj.timestamp);
    } 

struct structure getter(Obj this){
  printf("Value is still there: %d\n", this->struct_in_obj.timestamp);
  return this->struct_in_obj;
}

int main(){
  Obj obj = newObj();
  setVal(obj, /*8 bytes representing timestamp*/);
  struct structure A;
  A = getter(obj);
  printf("Here value disappears: %d\n", A.timestamp);
}
```

If I make getter only for this `double` value - it works. Why do I get 0 in timestamp after I copy structure? Is there a way to make it work like this or it's better to use additional getter for `double` value?

Comment: If that is really a double, %d is the wrong printf format string. But a compilable, runnable example would make answering a lot easier.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: Can you show us the class you have made and the structure, definition I mean.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which of course shows structure definitions as well as type-aliases. Also, for some (specified) input, what is the expected and actual output? And if you get warnings when compiling, please show those too (and if not then enable more warnings).

Comment: This code doesn't compile, so what you run to get your results must be something other than what you have shown. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment in the code,  `timestamp` seems to be of type `double` and you're trying to print the value using `%d`. That is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Then why %d gives me the correct value and %f gives 0?

Comment: @PaulPonomarev If it works with `"%d"`, then the structure member is an integer and not a floating point type.

Comment: Tried to change timestamp type to int and long(sizeof too, of course)..with those types I get undefined behaviour, or I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Thanks to you I found the reason and thanks to [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/892509-converting-8-bytes-integer) I understood how it should be. Long type wasn't enough